# Power Bi DAX, Getting last non-null value by identifier and date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get the last non null value on a table visualization and last non null value offset from a set of data that consists of a worker ID, dates and their shifts. (First image is how the table is loaded)

[image: data table]

On the table visualization on my report, i need to show the last non-null shift for those workers by last date, and the same with offset for the previous date that exists. (The output that i need)

[image: output]

I'm having trouble getting the correct DAX for filtering by worker ID and then by date to get the columns i need for output (tried both calculated column and measure with no success).

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you show what the final output should look like?  I'm having trouble following what the offset is

Comment: Ah ok, why are some of the cells highlighted with yellow rectangles?

Comment: Fixed the output that i need (in each case filtered by a diferent Worker ID). i need to create the last non-null column and the last non-null offset column. The offset is just the last non-null column "delayed" by a row.

Comment: Sorry, the yellow rectangles were just to show that the new column takes the last non-null value from the shift column.

Answer (score 0):

The following two measures should do the trick - please adjust to the correct table and column names.

[image]

```
Last NON NULL =
VAR currentDate =
    MAX ( Shifts[Date] )
VAR lastShift =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Shifts[Date] ),
        NOT ( Shifts[Shift] = BLANK () ),
        Shifts[Date] < currentDate
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Shifts[Shift] ) = BLANK (),
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Shifts[Shift] ),
            Shifts[Date] = lastShift,
            REMOVEFILTERS ( Shifts[Shift] )
        ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Shifts[Shift] )
    )


Last Non Null Offset =
VAR currentDate =
    MAX ( Shifts[Date] )
VAR lastShift =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Shifts[Date] ),
        Shifts[Date] < currentDate,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Shifts )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Last NON NULL],
        Shifts[Date] = lastShift,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Shifts[Shift] )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses Power Query transforms instead of calculated columns in DAX. This solution is obviously only applicable if you are able to transform the data in Power Query before loading to the model. If you are connected live to a dataset, a DAX approach is required.

If you **can** transform the data, this approach makes a more efficient data model once loaded, since calculated columns need to be refreshed every time you make a change to your data model. The data model will also be compressed more efficiently by the VertiPaq engine by using computed (in Power Query) vs. calculated (DAX) columns.

It uses the `FillUp` function combined with correct sorting of the input table to achieve your first desired column in `Shift_Filled`.

From there it uses a custom function `last_shift_func` to extract the information required by your second column, to `Shift_Last`. Note that the custom function relies on the table being sorted the same way as when calculating `Shift_Filled`.

You can paste the following into a new blank query to see the steps:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [ID="ABC",Date="2022-11-06",Shift="Shift 1"],
        [ID="XYZ",Date="2022-11-06",Shift="Shift 2"],
        [ID="JKL",Date="2022-11-06",Shift="Shift 2"],
        [ID="ABC",Date="2022-11-07",Shift="Shift 2"],
        [ID="XYZ",Date="2022-11-07",Shift="Shift 2"],
        [ID="JKL",Date="2022-11-07",Shift="Shift 1"],
        [ID="ABC",Date="2022-11-08",Shift=null],
        [ID="XYZ",Date="2022-11-08",Shift="Shift 1"],
        [ID="JKL",Date="2022-11-08",Shift=null],
        [ID="ABC",Date="2022-11-09",Shift=null],
        [ID="XYZ",Date="2022-11-09",Shift="Shift 2"],
        [ID="JKL",Date="2022-11-09",Shift=null],
        [ID="ABC",Date="2022-11-10",Shift="Shift 1"],
        [ID="XYZ",Date="2022-11-10",Shift=null]
    }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"ID", Order.Descending}, {"Date", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Shift", "Shift_Filled", type text),
    Buffered_Table = Table.Buffer(Table.FillUp(#"Duplicated Column",{"Shift_Filled"})),

    last_shift_func = (ID as text, Date as date, Table as table) =>
        let 
            val = Table.SelectRows(Buffered_Table, each [ID] = ID and [Date] < Date)[Shift_Filled]{0}
        in
            val,

    Added_col = Table.AddColumn(Buffered_Table, "Shift_Last", each try last_shift_func([ID], [Date], Buffered_Table) otherwise null, type text)


in
    Added_col
```